# Swift UI, Use Picker, forEach and Section together has error

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui, ios13, xcode11

I am using ForEach() inside a Picker, but the debug gives an error.

Xcode Version 11.2 (11B52)

```
var radiusRangeKM = Array((stride(from: 50, to: 2010, by: 10)))

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            //TODO: Form Set Up
            Form {

                Section() {
                    Picker(selection: $selectedRadius, label: Text("Radius(KM)")) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< radiusRangeKM.count, id: \.self) {
                            Text(String(self.radiusRangeKM[$0])).tag($0)
                        }
                    }

                }


            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Settings"))
        }
}
```

**Error on debug window**

[TableView] Warning once only: UITableView was told to layout its visible cells and other contents without being in the view hierarchy (the table view or one of its superviews has not been added to a window). This may cause bugs by forcing views inside the table view to load and perform layout without accurate information (e.g. table view bounds, trait collection, layout margins, safe area insets, etc), and will also cause unnecessary performance overhead due to extra layout passes. Make a symbolic breakpoint at UITableViewAlertForLayoutOutsideViewHierarchy to catch this in the debugger and see what caused this to occur, so you can avoid this action altogether if possible, or defer it until the table view has been added to a window. Table view: <_TtC7SwiftUIP33_BFB370BA5F1BADDC9D83021565761A4925UpdateCoalescingTableView: 0x7f9d5e98b000; baseClass = UITableView; frame = (0 0; 414 842); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = ; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, -108}; contentSize: {414, 8702.0000000000109}; adjustedContentInset: {108, 0, 34, 0}; dataSource: <_TtGC7SwiftUIP13$7fff2c6b223419ListCoreCoordinatorGVS_20SystemListDataSourceOs5Never_GOS_19SelectionManagerBoxS2___: 0x7f9d5cf80c50>>

### Update on Dec-16-2019

Update your iOS system to 13.3, it will work well on the real iPhone, but the warning still there.

Comment: It is not due to your code. Looks like an issue inside SwiftUI. I recommend to ignore it, or you can submit Apple Radar.

Comment: you can't just ignore it, coz when you test it on the phone, the selection is not working at all